# Statistical Signifigance Quadratics in Multiple Regression?

Tags: multiple-regression

To test the statistical significance of a variable you choose to make quadratic in a multiple regression model, should you use an F test to test the joint significance of the linear term and the matching quadratic term?

Comment: You would use an ANOVA to test whether the quadratic term significantly improves the model.